# How to make a self-made bash_profile recognized by the terminal?

Tags: bash, shell, path

My intention is to customize the prompt color and font style of the terminal. There are a couple of tutorials online on this subject but all of them involves a modification of the file `bash_profile` which for some reason does not exist in my computer (Mac OS X Sierra). I have two questions:

1) If I were to create my own `bash_profile` file, what should I do to get my system recognize and execute it everytime I start a new terminal session? Simply creating a file named `bash_profile` and place it in my home folder does not seem to be a complete step.

2) I know that `bash_profile` can also contain the PATH variable while in my computer (which does not have it) the paths are specified in `.paths` file. If I create my own `bash_profile`, shall I also copy all paths already contained in `.paths` into the bash_profile so as to make them consistent?

Comment: It's `.bash_profile`, there's a leading dot. Also see if you have a file called `.profile`, Bash reads that too, but only if it doesn't find `.bash_profile`, so you may or may not want to copy any contents over.

Comment: No, I don't have .profile in my home directory.

Comment: Interactive *non-login* shells read `~/.bashrc` not `~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There needs to be a `.` before `bash_profile`.  As long as `.bash_profile` is located at `~`, bash should pick it up.  You may want to `source` `.profile` if you have one, as creating a `.bash_profile` may prevent bash from reading from `.profile`.  Files that begin with `.` are hidden by `ls` by default;  use `ls -A` to list them.
2. You can append to your existing `PATH` by adding the following line to your `.bash_profile`:  `export PATH="${NEW_DIRECTORY}:${PATH}"`, replacing `${NEW_DIRECTORY}` with a directory of your choosing.  Colons delimit entries to `PATH`.

Comment: So is it like any unix system is programmed to automatically detect any file named `.bash_profile` if it is placed in ~?
What is the difference between executing `source .bash_profile` and not (just placing .bash_profile in home directory)?

Comment: (1) If that UNIX system contains bash, then yes.  But this has nothing to do with UNIX/POSIX, and everything to do with the fact that bash itself is what's been programmed to look for `~/.bash_profile`.  

(2) bash looks at different files in different situations.  If you `source .bash_profile` in one of those files, then you are mixing those situations together.  Depending on what you're trying to do, this may or may not be desirable.

Answer (score 0):

1. You should make sure that your terminal uses the `bash` shell as the login shell.  If it does, it will automatically source the `.bash_profile` file in your home directory when you open a new terminal.

   To change your login shell on macOS, bring up the Systems Preference panel and select "Users & Groups". In the list of users, right-click on your user and select "Advanced Options".  Make sure that your login shell is set to `/bin/bash` (where my shell is set to `/bin/ksh` in the picture below).

[image: Advanced Options user's section on macOS]

2. Your computer, running a flavour of Unix, *does* have a `PATH` variable in the shell,  and it may be modified in the `.bash_profile` file if you so wish.  To add a `/new/directory/bin` to the end of the `PATH` variable, use

   ```
    PATH="$PATH:/new/directory/bin"
   ```

   As far as I know, some of the settings that may be specified in `.path` files are specific to the `ksh93` shell. I am not familiar enough with this feature of the `ksh93` shell to be able to say with certainty whether all or some of its functionality may be transferred into your `.bash_profile` file.

Comment: Yes I use bash shell. I think I will just leave the paths to be specified in `PATH` for now.